# Compilation issues ("Unresolved reference") when Trying to build an app for Android (using Kotlin, Compose in Android Studio)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

When experimenting with the Kotlin language and its "Compose" library, I am encountering problems with some examples (which I looked up on the site of Android, so I suppose the example should be more or less OK).

More precisely, some imports (specified in the examples) yield error messages such as:

```
Unresolved reference: Card
```

for the import:

```
import androidx.compose.material.Card
```

needed for the following snippet:

```
@Composable
fun MyCard() {
    Card {
        Text("Card Content")
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if the error has to do with:

- The IDE (Android Studio).
- Some plugin missing.
- A problem with the libraries.

I would appreciate any advice / hint on how to proceed from here.

For completeness: the other imports relating to Compose are:

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.selection.toggleable
import androidx.compose.material3.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
```

Additional infos:

```
Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8609683, built on May 18, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.4
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 8
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: org.jetbrains.kotlin (212-1.6.21-release-334-AS5457.46)
```

Gradle dependencies (generated by Android Studio):

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha01'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_version"
}
```

Comment: If you asked about that, your question would be on topic for this site, right here. Asking for help finding other resources, however, is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Can you add the relevant dependencies to your question? (ie. `androidx.compose.material...`)

Comment: I saw that you added your imports etc, but can you include your Gradle dependencies? If you haven't added anything to them then that's likely your issue. There's all the information you need in the [Getting Started](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup) section of the Compose docs.

Comment: Add this :   implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"

Comment: Yep, as @CodePoet said you don't have the Material dependency to use `androidx.compose.material.Card`, however I would probably recommend sticking with one library, the M3 library should have everything you need (including the M3 `Card`) if you're just playing experimenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your Compose Material 3 dependency in your `build.gradle` file to version `1.1.0-alpha02` to use `Card`

```
implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha02'
```

Then all you need to do in your code is to import

```
import androidx.compose.material3.*
```

to use all Material 3 components available in your code

Answer (score 0):

Have you added **@ExperimentalMaterial3Api** as per the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#Card(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.foundation.BorderStroke,androidx.compose.material3.CardElevation,androidx.compose.material3.CardColors,kotlin.Function1))?
Maybe that is the issue?

Edit: If you are using Material 3, then you need to remove this import:

```
import androidx.compose.material.Card
```

Also, for info, the Material 3 dependencies are now at [**1.0.0-alpha13**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material3#declaring_dependencies):

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha13"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size-class:1.0.0-alpha13"
}
```

If you are using Material 2, then you need to add this to your dependencies:

```
implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
```

Comment: The question is about the Material 2 library, not Material 3 which is experimental.

Comment: Well he is using material3 imports...

Comment: There is one M3 reference (`import androidx.compose.material3.*`) but the `Card` import is M2 (`import androidx.compose.material.Card`)?

Answer (score 0):

First, update your dependencies.

If the issue persists and you are very sure your code has no issues, then run `./gradlew clean`
This command deletes the build directory, then run again your project. I hope this helps